# Bayesian rating values on entries page

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

I use the Rating module.
I need to get bayesian rating value for every entry but not simply average summ. Is it possible?

The part of my template (this is standard example for Rating module usage):

```
{exp:rating:rank collection="Book Reviews" orderby="bayesian:overall" limit="10" paginate="bottom" dynamic="off"}
    <div class="entries">
       <h4>{exp:rating:stats collection="Book Reviews" entry_id="{entry_id}" precision="1"}<span style="float:right;">{stars_overall_avg} ({overall_avg}/5, based on {overall_count} review{if overall_count !="1"}s{/if})</span>{/exp:rating:stats}
       <a href="{url_title_path='rating_main/entry'}">{title}</a></h4>
       <p><b><u>{entry_id}</u></b></p>
       <p>Author: <a href="{path='rating_main/author_profile'}/{author_id}/">{author}</a></p>
       <p>Description: {if summary}{summary}{if:else}{body}{/if}</p>
   </div>
   {if rating_no_results}<p>No results.</p>{/if}
   {rating_paginate}
       <hr />
      <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages &nbsp; {pagination_links}</p>
   {/rating_paginate}
{/exp:rating:rank}
```

[image]

Best regards,
Aleksey

Comment: Can you please update your question with your template code, specifically the tags you're using from Rating and the variables inside.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to write a custom plugin for this. It should be simple enough to pass an entry ID to a plugin, and then from the plugin query for the needed rating data and follow an algorithm to calculate the rating you need.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I use Rating module which already contains entries ordering by this algorithm. Rating of each entry calculates by bayesian algorithm. But I can't receive the results of those calculations in such important place.

Comment: Unfortunately built-in Bayesian value display isn't available in Rating. Calculating this value using PHP would be the way to go, as suggested in this answer. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions